# How to change this background color on Graph Editor

Tags: 3d-view, graph-editor

I need to change this portion of the background in the Graph Editor if possible. I can't see the "hide" button with this white background, and makes me confuse while animating. I searched on the Themes but had no luck. Would appreciate if you can help me, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you specified a lot of custom colors, but just to get the default settings you could simply choose a preset:

[image]

Comment: Most of the settings are under Preferences > Themes> Graph Editor > Theme Space List, but there doesn't seem to be a setting for the entry background as far as I can see although you can change the area background which is called Source List.

Comment: At first I tried this, but the background still is white, I don't know why.

Comment: When I switch from this foot.R bone to the Hand.L bone, it changes to yellow, do you know where can I change the colors?